# Maximum value of a sum of logs

Tags: statistics, logarithms

In *Introduction to Stochastic Dynamic Programming* it says the best value of $a$ at the equation

$$\max_a[ p(\log(1+a)+q\log(1-a) ]$$  is $(q - p)$, knowing that $q = 1 - p$. I can't see where is this simple calculus.

[Link](http://www.deeplearningitalia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Introduction-to-Stochastic-Dynamic-Programming-Ross.pdf) of the book (Page 7).

Comment: Consider $$x \mapsto p\log(1+x)+q\log(1-x)$$

Comment: Hi! I didnt get it